# Gvim, map "prompt" shows up as blank or dot dot dot... redraw?

Tags: vim

Many of the navigation and other commands I use frequently, I try to make key maps for. For instance,

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>f :find<Space>
```

However, where I expect a prompt starting with `:find`, I get no text, until I start typing, or switch applications, it is blank (or sometimes `.....`).

Is this normal? Is there a way around this?

By the way, I am on kubuntu, and got my GVim via `apt-get install vim-gtk`.

Comment: You should remove `<silent>`.

Comment: @romainl, @#$!%&, now I know why I don't want it. I'll go read on why I would ever. (Suppress error messages?) Thank you! This solved it for me, so if you'll submit it as answer, I can mark this question as solved please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `<silent>` as its purpose is precisely to *silence* the ex commands in the right hand side of your mapping.

`<silent>` is obviously counterproductive in this case but it can be useful when your mapping does a lot of stuff with possibly annoying echos.